# completely removing href links with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have built a jquery slider for my website. There are 3 slides in total and each slide contains 30-40 images linking through to a separate page.

I would like to completely remove the href links on the slides that are not active, and then add them in again when the slide is active. I have tried a few methods such as:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

But this only prevents the link clicking through and doesn't actually remove it.

Any suggestions on what i could do?

The reason i would like to do this is because Google doesn't like more than 100 internal links on a page and i have nearly double that!

Thanks, Dan

Comment: $('a').removeAttr('href')

Comment: What you mean google doesn't like.Are you saying it's not SEO freindly?

Comment: Could you please show a snippet of the code that takes ypu to the next image in a slide?

Comment: If you are doing this for google, DON'T. The bots won't look at your code *after* you have made changes from JS. There is another way to achieve it, but @DavidFregoli seems to have explained it already. :-)

Comment: @ Varinder Singh yes not SEO friendly. It's not a major issue but would like to get it sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please be aware that google will scrape the original code and won't pay attention to the one resulting in js manipulations.

you can start without href in the dom and have something like

```
<a data-href="url">
```

when the event for image sliding in fires you can activate it with:

```
$(this).attr('href', $(this).data('href'))
```

or you could actually activate them all at once on dom ready

```
$('#carousel a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).data('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your code, why do you listen to the click event ?
If you wan't to deactivate them, you can put `$("a").css("display","none");` then set it back later. If you wan't to completly remove the html, it's `$("a").remove();`

Anyway, this won't help you. Google's indexer don't have javascript enabled, you have to change your raw html.

Comment: the code above was just a rough example, thanks for the other advice

Answer (score 1):

If you cant for some reason, try this on the currently active image

```
$("active image identifier selector a").attr("href", "link to add");
$("all images selector").not("active image identifier selector").find("a").removeAttr("href")
```

Mind you using removeAttr does not disable the link, it removes it totally, not sure if thats what you want to do. Just to confirm, do you want the links deactivated or removed at all.

e.preventDefault only disables the link but not remove it.

Say you have the 2nd image active and you do something like $("images a").attr("href", "link to add"), how would you know what link to add to that image and preceeding images when they become active because you have pretty much discarded the href attribute.

A solution I will suggest is to store the link in a data attribute for a link like

```
//store href in link data for each link to be deactivated
$("all images selector").not("active image identifier selector").each(function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    //get url of link
    var url = $this.attr("href");

    //store url in a data attribute for that link
    $this.data("my-url", url);

    $(this).removeAttr("href");
});

//get data attribute of active image and readd href attribute
$("active image identifier selector a").attr("href", $("active image identifier selector a").data("my-url"));
```

Try this and let me know if that helps.
Mind you its not the most effiecient way of doing it. There may be more optimized functions to loop over the links but getting it to work is priority first here I assume for you.

Cheers.

Comment: i would like them completly removed from the html when not active and then re-added when that particular slide is active.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. trying what I have above should do the trick if theres no typos in it but where would you get the source of the links when readding them after removing?

Comment: will adding the links via js help in anyway? rather then trying to remove them?

Comment: Yes that would work but I assume the links for each image is diferent so if you had lots of images you'd have a lot of hardcoding to do. I will edit my answer to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: well i am actually using WordPress so getting the links would be fairly easy by just getting the permalink.

Comment: Yes true you can get the link but wordpress does not work in the context of javascript, its php so when dynamically setting the link in javascript, you dont have php functions available at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Using **javascript:void(0)** in **href** user will not go to next page and no more url is used in page.

Try this code:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    $(this).attr("href","javascript:void(0)");
})
```